# PHP object Operator Precedence (->)

Tags: php

I write some code:

```
class a{
    public $b=['f'=>'c'];
}
$a=new a;
$b='b';
echo $a->$b['f'];
```

When I use cli,it output 'c',but when I use apache http server,throw an error`Illegal string offset 'f'`,so I don't know which precedence is higher between `->` and `[`.There is no introduction about `->` on http://php.net. My PHP version is 5.6 and use windows 10.In Linux cli and httpd will output 'c'

Comment: echo $a->b['f']; please no dollar before the b

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator precedence. It is simply impossible for the interpreter to tell what you meant here - did you mean to access a variable `$b`, or `$b['f']`? `$a->{$b}['f']` would be the “proper” way to do this. Oh, and if you are using CLI for development purposes - then enable proper error reporting in that environment as well ...

Comment: @PhilippSander I know it will be work,but use variable variables will cause this problem

Comment: @CBroe I enabled error reporting ,perhaps the operation of cli and httpd is different.

Comment: CLI often uses a different php.ini, so you have to enable error reporting there as well.

Comment: @CBroe It's not difference about php.ini,because my php CLI's version is 7.x,so this is the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a general idea of the precedence order between `->` and `[`, you might want to take a look at the PHP7 migration documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect).
I know you are talking about PHP5, but the migration documents pays attention to this since the behaviour was changed between PHP5 and PHP7.

To answer your question, `$foo->$bar['baz']` is interpreted as `$foo->{$bar['baz']}` in PHP5. This means your code should be throwing an error because it is trying to access `$b['f']` while it is using `$b='b';` as the definition of `$b`.

However, in PHP7 it is interpreted as `($foo->$bar)['baz']`, so here it *should* be working as you expect.

Are you sure your CLI isn't using PHP7?

Comment: thanks for your answer,I think this is the reason.My CLI is 7.0 and Linux is PHP7.0 too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right - just get rid of that second $!

```
class a{
    public $b=['f'=>'c'];
}
$a=new a;
$b='b';
echo $a->b['f']; // without the $ it works
$x = $a->$b;  // otherwise you need to assign first
echo $x['f']; // now it works
echo $a->{$b}['f']; // or wrapped in curlies
```

see here https://3v4l.org/gZJWt

The precedence is given to $. In other words, $x->$b['f'] considers $b first to be an array, so it looks for $b['f'] which doesn't exist, hence your error. Putting the curly brackets around $b forces PHP to evaluate that first, giving you the value 'b', so it then becomes $x->b['f'], which exists and thus works.

Comment: yes ,I know your code is worked,but it not answer my question

Comment: I just updated it a little, I hope that makes it clear to you and answers your question

Answer (score -4):

What about echo ($a->$b)['f'];?

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a question. Please put questions in the comments section.

Comment: Well, I think it's an answer. If you use parentesis the problem with operators precedence dissapears...

Comment: For me it's working, but I'm testing it with PHP7. echo $a->{$b}['f']; should work also.

Comment: echo $a->{$b}['f']; works with php 7 and php 5.5, so it will work with php 5.6

Comment: @OnekO cli or httpd ,which operation system you used?