# Array to string conversion error on foreach on php 7.3 but work on php 5.6

Tags: php, foreach

I have upgraded my server to use PHP version 7.3 from 5.6
I ran compatibility check from PHPStorm for all my files, and it only showed me only weak warning for few of the codes but since I am no longer using those script I ignored it, but it does not point out anything wrong on this code.

But after migration, I found that this piece of code is not working as required. I have this code to get state short code when I pass the 2 digit country code.

```
$jsonitemfile = file_get_contents('countries-states.json');
$conobjitems = json_decode($jsonitemfile);
$findBystatename = function($constatename) use ($conobjitems) {
 foreach ($conobjitems->$_POST['Contact0Country']->states as $short => $outputstate) {
    if ($outputstate->name == $constatename) return $short;
 }

    return false;
};
$p2 = 'New York';
echo $findBystatename($p2) ?: $p2;
```

When I run this code I get the following error

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/domain.com/public_html/code/code_check.php on line 27
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Array in /home/domain.com/public_html/code/code_check.php on line 27
> Notice: Trying to get property 'states' of non-object in /home/domain.com/public_html/code/code_check.php on line 27
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/domain.com/public_html/code/code_check.php on line 27

The same code is working on PHP 5.6 without throwing any error.

Although I fixed the code by doing the below changes

```
$findBystatename = function($constatename) use ($conobjitems) {
$p1 = $_POST['Contact0Country'];    
 foreach ($conobjitems->$p1->states as $short => $outputstate) {
    if ($outputstate->name == $constatename) return $short;
 }
    return false;
};
```

For my learning curve can anyone please advise why its not working? And even with the updated code, if I define $p1 above the function, it start to throw the same error.
Also is there a way the original code start working on PHP 7.3 without updating the code?

Comment: You say 'error', but in fact all it throws is a warning. Does the code itself work? If so, you can just disable the errors from being output in your php.ini? Obviously the best thing is to update the code to work without warnings. You could just map() over the array instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP object Operator Precedence (->)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410769/php-object-operator-precedence)

Comment: @JeroenBourgois ah  yeah sorry about mentioning error, yeh after turning off the error notification, the code actually does not work, it gives the full state name instead of the required 2 digit state code in output

Answer (score 0):

`$conobjitems->$_POST['Contact0Country']->state` is ambiguous.  It could mean the `state` property of an object defined by `$conobjitems->$_POST['Contact0Country']` (as you and PHP 5.6 assume), or it could mean the `state` property of an object defined by `$_POST['Contact0Country']` and then whatever that resolves to as a property on `$conobjitems`, which seems to be what modern PHP considers it.

Obviously a compiler/run time environment cannot treat a line as meaning two things, so it has to pick one and move on, or error out and fail.  Historically PHP has been lenient in what it copes with, but as the language has improved and got faster some of that leniency has been removed in favour of making the coder be specific instead of ambiguous (which also helps make the code readable)

If this is just a toy example - this won't work, but your piece of code can be written as:

```
$jsonitemfile = file_get_contents('countries-states.json');
$conobjitems = json_decode($jsonitemfile);
$country=$conobjitems->$_POST['Contact0Country'];
$states=$country->states;

$findBystatename = function($constatename) use ($states) {
   foreach ($states as $short => $state) {
      if ($state->name == $constatename) return $short;
   }
   return false;
};

$p2 = 'New York';
echo $findBystatename($p2) ?: $p2;
```

`$country` could be skipped but it makes the code more readable, likewise separating the state list into `$states` before injecting into the closure makes it clear to the reader and PHP what you want to do.

By the way, since you seem to choose the country by user-input (which could be manipulated, even if you're using a drop down), you could also get an error, warning or exception when you create `$country` if that country doesn't exist in the `$conobjitems` set.  You could use [`property_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) first to make sure the country is found.